# how to get count and distinct count with group by in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I am having below mentioned dataframe:

```
Date         ID
2018-04-01   K-1
2018-04-01   K-1
2018-04-02   K-2
2018-04-02   K-2
2018-04-03   K-2
2018-04-04   K-3
2018-05-01   K-5
2018-05-01   K-5
2018-05-02   K-6
2018-05-02   K-7
```

by using above datafram i want below mentioned two matrix, group by date:

New_DF1

```
Date        Unique Count    Duplicate_Count
2018-04-01  1               1
2018-04-02  1               1
2018-04-03  1               0
2018-04-04  1               0
2018-05-01  1               0
2018-05-02  2               0
```

New_DF2

```
Month     Unique Count    Duplicate_Count
May-18    4               2
Apr-18    3               0
```

I have tried:

```
DF%>%
        group_by(Date) %>%
        summarise(count = n_distinct(ID))
```

but it couldn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what you are counting as unique and duplicate. Could you explain?

Comment: @LAP for `DF_1` the `Unique count` should be distinct count of `ID` and  `Duplicate_count` should be additional count of same `ID` (for example if there is only one `K-1` than it should be 0 if count of `K-1` is >1 let say 3 than it should be 2).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper From Date

Comment: Alright, can you explain why there's no unique but one duplicate for `2018-04-03` while there's only a  K-2 value, is it because of a mistake ? or because K2 is not unique on the whole column ?

Comment: And why in your `New_DF1` is `2018-05-03` absent ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks., sorry it was a mistake. I have corrected it now.

Comment: I think there is still one mistake, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
New_DF1 <- DF %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Unique_Count  = n_distinct(ID),
            Duplicate_Count = sum(table(ID)>1))

New_DF1
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#         Date Unique_Count Duplicate_Count
#       <fctr>        <int>           <int>
# 1 2018-04-01            1               1
# 2 2018-04-02            1               1
# 3 2018-04-03            1               0
# 4 2018-04-04            1               0
# 5 2018-05-01            1               1
# 6 2018-05-02            2               0

New_DF2 <- New_DF1 %>%
  group_by(month = format.Date(Date, "%b-%y")) %>%
  summarize_at(2:3,sum)

New_DF2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#    month Unique_Count Duplicate_Count
#    <chr>        <int>           <int>
# 1 Apr-18            4               2
# 2 May-18            3               1
```

With base `R`:

```
New_DF1<- aggregate(ID ~ Date, DF, function(x) c(Unique_Count  = length(unique(x)),
                           Duplicate_Count = sum(table(x)>1)))

New_DF1<- cbind(New_DF1[1],New_DF1[[2]])

New_DF1
#         Date Unique_Count Duplicate_Count
# 1 2018-04-01            1               1
# 2 2018-04-02            1               1
# 3 2018-04-03            1               0
# 4 2018-04-04            1               0
# 5 2018-05-01            1               1
# 6 2018-05-02            2               0

New_DF2 <- New_DF1
New_DF2$month = format.Date(New_DF2$Date, "%b-%y")
New_DF2 <- aggregate(cbind(Unique_Count, Duplicate_Count) ~ month, New_DF2, sum)

New_DF2
#    month Unique_Count Duplicate_Count
# 1 Apr-18            4               2
# 2 May-18            3               1
```

Comment: Thanks it worked., How can i do the same for `New_DF2` by deriving month from date.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
DF%>%
        group_by(Date, ID) %>%
        summarise(Unique_Count  = n_distinct(ID),
                  Duplicate_Count = n())
```